# Unable to correctly filter by dates in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, lubridate

I'm having my first go using date variables as a filter for a Shiny app I'm putting together, and I'm having trouble understanding why the code returns no cases. I've pre-processed the data in `mydf` (here just consisting of the variable I'm having trouble with) using the `lubridate` package. I've been attempting various ways including `as.Date`, `as_date`, etc. without success. What am I missing?

Code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- structure(list(EndDate = structure(c(17345, 17344, 17343, 17341, 
                                 17341, 17340, 17340, 17339, 17339, 17339, 17339, 17339, 17339, 
                                 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 
                                 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17338, 17337, 
                                 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 17337, 
                                 17336, 17336, 17336, 17336, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 17335, 
                                 17335, 17335, 17335, 17334, 17334, 17334, 17334, 17334, 17334, 
                                 17334, 17334, 17334, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 
                                 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 
                                 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 
                                 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17333, 17332, 17332, 
                                 17332, 17332, 17332, 17332, 17332, 17331, 17331, 17331, 17331, 
                                 17331, 17331, 17331, 17331, 17331, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 
                                 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 
                                 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 
                                 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17330, 17324, 17322, 
                                 17318, 17338, 17335), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                   "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -142L), .Names = "EndDate")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("date", "Select dates",
          min = min(mydf$EndDate),
          max = max(mydf$EndDate),
          value = c(min(mydf$EndDate), max(mydf$EndDate))),
  tableOutput("filtered_data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filt_data <- reactive({
    filter(mydf, input$date[1] >= EndDate, input$date[2] <= EndDate)
  })

  output$filtered_data <- renderTable({
filt_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have your filter conditions backwards from what you want. And, to display `Enddate` as dates in the outputted shiny table, one solution is to convert the dates to characters. See below:

```
 filt_data <- reactive({
    results = filter(mydf, EndDate >= input$date[1] & EndDate <= input$date[2] )

    # To avoid displaying dates as integers in outputted table
    results$EndDate = as.character(results$EndDate) 
    results
  })
```